# Django Allauth seems to log user out after a few days of inactivity

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-allauth

When a user logs in, I want the user to stay logged in indefinitely unless of course they themselves prompt the log out.

What seems to be the case with my website (using django-allauth for authentication) is that when a user logs in and then doesn't go on the website for a few days (haven't tested exactly how many days) it loses their authentication and they're no longer logged in.

I want the authentication state to be permanent and not expire.

Can someone explain this please and tell me how to achieve what i want.

tried looking into session cookie expiry and researching defaults. Haven't got far.

Comment: did you have a look at SESSION_COOKIE_AGE setting?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems you're looking for this setting ([django-allauth](https://django-allauth.readthedocs.io/en/stable/configuration.html)):

> **ACCOUNT_SESSION_REMEMBER (=None)**
>
> **Controls the life time of the session**. Set to None to ask the user (“Remember me?”), False to not remember, and True to always remember.

You might want to combine this with a considerable large `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE`.

Answer (score 0):

As said in the comments you have to set the `SESSION_COOKIE_AGE` value.

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/settings/#session-cookie-age) the default value is 2 weeks.